# Kafka threw exception disk error when trying to access log file on the disk

Tags: apache-kafka

My Kafka cluster (10 nodes,5 zk nodes) suddenly threw **disk error** exception as following:

```
ERROR [ReplicaFetcher replicaId=196790673, 
leaderId=196790680, fetcherId=0] 
Error for partition test-topic-23 at offset 1012839
(kafka.server.ReplicaFetcherThread)
org.apache.kafka.common.errors.KafkaStorageException: 
Disk error when trying to access log file on the disk
```

So my Kafka producer and consumer failed, but I still can create a new topic with 36 partitions and 2 replicats, and I can write/read from the new topic. When I tried read/write old topic in command line, sometimes good and sometimes failed.

I also tried create a file/folder on disk, it was also ok. So I'm confused why Kafka threw disk error exception.

Comment: It happened suddenly at my docker's, too. It appeared the first time after several weeks of working and never changing config, that, when it had to work after a reboot and to store some producer message. I thought it has something to do with my producer, but it looks like a bug of the kafka broker. I need help, too.

Comment: Happened with our Kafka cluster today .. and all the nodes went down...

Answer (score 0):

This is going to sound very obvious, but the primary thing to check if you get a Disk error, is the disk. Is it corrupted, or perhaps is there simply a full partition?

Also note that maybe the disk still works a little bit, or you might have multiple disks, so a test like 'I can still use some disk' does not give too much information.